# C# API Endpoint Equivalent of Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I am attempting to rewrite some Javadscript code to c# but stuck on 2 questions.

This it the original code:

```
module.exports = () => {
    const app = express.Router();
    app.get('/', cors(), validUrl, (req, res, next) => {
        switch (req.query.responseType) {
    case 'blob':
        req.pipe(request(req.query.url).on('error', next)).pipe(res);
        break;
    case 'text':
    default:
        request({url: req.query.url, encoding: 'binary'}, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                return next(error);
            }
            res.send(
            `data:${response.headers['content-type']};base64,${Buffer.from(
                body,
                'binary'
            ).toString('base64')}`
        );
    });
    }
});
```

Full code is here:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas-proxy-nodejs/blob/master/server.js

This is where I have got to:

```
public static class Html2CanvasProxy
{
    [FunctionName("Html2CanvasProxy")]
    public static async Task<string> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> queryParams = req.GetQueryParameterDictionary();
        queryParams.TryGetValue("url", out string url);
        queryParams.TryGetValue("responseType: ", out string responseType);

        using var client = new HttpClient();
        byte[] bytes;

        switch (responseType)
        {
            case "blob":
                // what to do if it's a "blob"?
                return "What is the equivalent of req.pipe(request(req.query.url).on('error', next)).pipe(res);";
            case "text":
                // what to do if it's "text"? - is this correct?
                bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }

        return "Error";
    }
}
```

I cannot work out what is happening at this line:

```
req.pipe(request(req.query.url).on('error', next)).pipe(res);
```

and how to convert it to c#

I am also stuck on what the return type should be? Just an object?

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consuming-web-api-in-dotnet-using-httpclient

Comment: First of all, debug the javascript, find out what req is, use console.log() to figure out what that line does. I would do a few of console.logs, but what I can see is that pipe(request(req.query.url).on('error', next)). on is an event, if it errors, then goes to the next request

Comment: there is no return type, it sends something, but the code is not waiting for anything to return back, it is a void method

Comment: @Iria does my "text" switch look correct to you?

Comment: `TryGetValue` returns a `bool` indicating whether the value was retrieved successfully or not. You may want to consider checking the result before using the value.

Comment: you are using c#, but .net core 2.2? 3.1? standard? ...

Comment: @Iria 3.1 .net core

Comment: honestly, I would use Endpoints to deal with this, instead of 'translating' from javascript to 3.1 net core. Understand what it does, then do it in the framework that you're working on

Comment: You need to use ASP.NET Core Web API for this.